# Google calendar CORS error

Tags: jquery, json, google-calendar-api

I am trying to get json data from google calendar using this jquery piece of code:

```
var calendar_json_url = "http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/some-@gmail.com/public/full?orderby=starttime&sortorder=ascending&max-results=3&futureevents=true&alt=json";

  // Get list of upcoming events formatted in JSON
  jQuery.getJSON(calendar_json_url, function(data){

    // Parse and render each event
    jQuery.each(data.feed.entry, function(i, item){

      // Render the event
      jQuery("#gcal-events li").last().after( "<li>" + item.title.$t + "</li>" );
    });
  });
```

but the problem is that I keep receiving "Cross-Origin Request Blocked" error. I don't want to  use default google calendar. I just need the data and want to reformat it in another way!
Am I doing something wrong?
when I add &callback=? the error doesn't appear anymore, but it doesn't get the data too!

Answer (score 2):

The browser security model restricts scripts from accessing data delivered from domains other than the one from which the page was loaded, unless the **server** enables Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (Read the [Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/), or a [more readable discussion from Adobe](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/understanding-cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors.html)).

It appears Google doesn't enable CORS requests on its feeds. From what I'm seeing, you'll have to register as a developer and use the JavaScript API to make Cross-Origin requests: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/dev/dev_jscript#Option3UseCORS

Comment: Thanks for your great advice. I was reading the api guide before and I was wondering why should we register as a developer first.

Comment: If this solved your issue, please mark it as an "Accepted" answer so it doesn't show up in the list of unanswered questions, and can provide guidance for future searchers.